# PHP LOAD DATA INFILE Error Reading File

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Solved**

So, it was a type of permission error. Earlier in this script, I used flock() on the file to make sure the file wasn't being written to by another script. Removing flock() allows the query to run. Now I just need to determine a way to not load a file if it is still being written to...

---

I'm having trouble getting LOAD DATA INFILE to work in my php script. Here's the relevant portions of the script:

```
... //set $host, $user, etc.
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => 1));
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
... //set $sqlFile and $table
$sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$sqlFile' REPLACE INTO TABLE `$table`";
echo $sql . "\n";
$rows = $pdo->exec($sql);
```

Running the script then produces:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:/pathToTemp/emdr/emdrorders/emdrorders_160314-1947UTC.txt'
REPLACE INTO TABLE `emdrorders`
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2 Error reading file 'D:\pathToTemp\emdr\emdrorders\emdrorders_160314-1947UTC.txt'
(Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

However, if I run the same query through the mysql cli it works.

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:/pathToTemp/emdr/emdrorders/emdrorders_160314-1947UTC.txt'
REPLACE INTO TABLE `emdrorders`;
Query OK, 5487 rows affected (0.10 sec)
Records: 5355  Deleted: 132  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

I've also tried using LOCAL, but instead of throwing an exception `$pdo->exec()` returns 0 and the data is not loaded into the database.

My Mysql is 5.6.12 and PHP is 5.4.16 on a Windows machine and planning to put it on linux server. (I'm also doing this within the Laravel framework but I don't think that would cause this problem.)

Since the query works in the mysql cli but not through php, I can only assume the problem is in the php settings or the pdo. What do I need to change?

Comment: sounds like PHP does not have permission to access that file. It's terribly insecure, but what happens if you chmod -r 777 D:/pathToTemp/emdr/emdrorders/ ?

Comment: does `is_readable('D:/pathToTemp/emdr/emdrorders/emdrorders_160314-1947UTC.txt')` return true same with `is_writable`?

Comment: @Victory Both is_readable and is_writable return true.

Comment: @Lee PHP has permission to that directory as another script writes the files I'm attempting to import.

Comment: try `query` instead of `exec`

Answer (score 0):

What is it that you plan on doing with `$rows`?

You pass queries through `PDO::QUERY` or `PDO::PREPARE`.

I assume from the use of `PDOStatement::execute` that you wish to use `PDO::PREPARE`.

`$query = $pdo->prepare($sql); $query->execute();`

To obtain responses from the query:
`$query->fetch()` or `$query->fetchAll()`

See link for documentation on preparing a query in PDO:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php